# How to listen for button presses on a bluetooth speaker on windows

Tags: java, windows, audio, bluetooth, listener

Is there anyway to listen for a specific button press on a Bluetooth speaker and use that to run a method? Ive seen multiple examples of the Android questions asking this?

The buttons on the Bluetooth speaker are"play" "stop" "next" "back" and "call".

I know this is possible as I have seen an android app use button presses on earphones to pause the game.

This is the bluetooth speaker in question. http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Waterproof-Wireless-Car-Bluetooth-Shower-Music-Speaker-Handsfree-MIC-Suction-/321406813893?var=&hash=item4ad556c6c

Are the button presses like normal keyboard strokes? Then I can listen for it

Comment: Hello, have you fount anything ? I want the same with a smart tracker Bluetooth, to listen to a button click

Comment: @Vasilisfoo, hello! did you find a solution to this task?